# Postgresql : Average over a limit of Date with group by

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

```
item_id    date          number
1          2000-01-01    100
1          2003-03-08    50
1          2004-04-21    10
1          2004-12-11    10
1          2010-03-03    10
2          2000-06-29    1
2          2002-05-22    2
2          2002-07-06    3
2          2008-10-20    4
```

I'm trying to get the average for each uniq Item_id over the last 3 dates.
It's difficult because there are missing date in between so a range of hardcoded dates doesn't always work.

I expect a result like :

```
item_id   MyAverage
1          10
2          3
```

I don't really know how to do this. Currently i manage to do it for one item but i have trouble extending it to multiples items :

```
SELECT AVG(MyAverage.number) FROM ( 
  SELECT date,number 
  FROM item_list 
  where item_id = 1 
  ORDER BY date  DESC limit 3
) as MyAverage;
```

My main problem is with generalising the `"DESC limit 3"` over a `group by id`.

attempt :

```
SELECT item_id,AVG(MyAverage.number) 
FROM ( 
  SELECT item_id,date,number 
  FROM item_list 
  ORDER BY date  DESC limit 3) as MyAverage 
GROUP BY item_id;
```

The limit is messing things up there.

I have made it " work " using between date and date but it's not working as i want because i need a limit and not an hardcoded date..

Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to assign `1` to `3` for the records with the last date for an ID an then filter for that.

```
SELECT x.item_id,
       avg(x.number)
       FROM (SELECT il.item_id,
                    il.number,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY il.item_id
                                       ORDER BY il.date DESC) rn
                    FROM item_list il) x
       WHERE x.rn BETWEEN 1 AND 3
       GROUP BY x.item_id;
```

Comment: so if id need the last 200 records i'd just do BETWEEN 1 AND 200 ?  it's not entirely clear to me how OVER / partition work i need to look into that. 
It seems to be working but it took around 3 minutes to resolve so i might need to look for a different solution  / reorganise my data i have around 100 millions rows for 100k uniq item_ids.

Comment: @begindav: Yes, that would be `BETWEEN 1 AND 200`. And try an index on `item_list (item_id, date)` or `item_list (item_id, date, number)`.

Comment: didn't help actually made it 10% worst  ( but that might be because less ram on my computer ). maybe i'll query each id individually since it would be much faster ? query per id is 0.008ms so that would be around 0.8sec total  for 100k uniq item_id if done in the back end vs 3minutes in sql.

Comment: looks like it's not using indexes after running explain analyze, it's kind of strange